# Why can't I play Destiny on a new PS4 after it has been downloaded?

Tags: destiny

I was sharing a PS4 with a friend. I bought games and downloaded them onto that system. He bought me a PS4 for Christmas. I downloaded all my games from his to mine. I can play all but Destiny. What do I do?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to start the game?

Answer (score 1):

Your license is tied to the other console. Destiny doesn't allow license sharing. You'll need to change your licenses for your new console, but doing so, will make make your bought licenses on your friend's PS4 invalid.

You could also try to make your new PS4 as your primary PS4 first (you can select that on network settings).